# Select and store values between line-breaks into list

Tags: python, css, list, web-scraping

I'm trying to select postcodes within line-breaks and storing them within a list. However, given the nature of the web-page I am finding it very difficult. I'm trying to assort this by hospital names, and gathering the hospital names is fine however there are many text between line-breaks so getting only the postcode is challenging.

Here is what I have tried:

```
l = ['http://www.wales.nhs.uk/ourservices/directory/Hospitals/92',
'http://www.wales.nhs.uk/ourservices/directory/Hospitals/62']

waleit = {'hospital':[],'address':[]}

asit = []

for url in l:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
    for s in soup.find('div',{'style':'width:500px; float:left; '}):
        soupy = s.find_next('h1')
        try:
            waleit['hospital'].append(soupy.text)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
    wel = soup.find('div',{'style':'width:500px; float:left; '})
    for a in wel.childGenerator():
        x=[a]
        print(x[0])
```

which prints:

```
<h1>Bronglais General Hospital</h1>

        Caradoc Road, Aberystwyth
<br/>
 SY23 1ER
<br/>
<br/>

        Tel: 01970 623131
<br/>
 
<br/>
Type of Hospital: Major acute  -  Major A&E - Open 24 hours
<br/>
```

How do I extract for specific text with `<br>...<br>` like the postcode?

expected output:

```
{'hospital': ['Bronglais General Hospital', 'Glan Clwyd Hospital'],
 'address': ['SY23 1ER','LL18 5UJ']}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting As requested, I have updated the question and added an expected output. This should be clear, I hope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. See below; note I used css selectors instead of `find()`; I just prefer them:

```
urls = ['http://www.wales.nhs.uk/ourservices/directory/Hospitals/92',
'http://www.wales.nhs.uk/ourservices/directory/Hospitals/62']

waleit = {'hospital':[],'address':[]}
hospitals,addresses = [],[]
for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
    data = list(soup.select_one("div[style='width:500px; float:left; ']").stripped_strings)
    hospitals.append(data[0])
    addresses.append(data[2])        
waleit['hospital']=hospitals
waleit['address']=addresses
waleit
```

Output:

```
{'hospital': ['Bronglais General Hospital', 'Glan Clwyd Hospital'],
 'address': ['SY23 1ER', 'LL18 5UJ']}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to use the css selector myself (I'm new to it), but could not figure it out. However, after looking at your approach I know what I have missed! I have not used `.stripped_Strings` before, my go to has always been `text.strip()` or `get_text(strip=True)`. This is refreshing, especially the inclusion of `list()`.  Thank you for this approach! It will be very helpful in my future workflow